# Iterating through array in Java (deducing a 1D from a 2D array)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, iteration, path-finding

I am trying to write a piece of Java code which can deduce a 1D integer array from a 2D integer array. My 2D array looks something like this:

```
Node1  Node2   Path
 6      8      501
 2      6      500 
 8      10     505 
 2      4      502
```

And my task is as follows. I want to find "Path"s from elements of the first column (Node 1) to the elements of the second column (Node2). I mean something like these:

Path from "2" to "8" would be `500 501` in that order. And path from "2" to "4" would be `502` (not `500` since it terminates at "6")

I have been trying to achieve this by iterating with simple for loop but have been struggling. Could someone please let me know how I can solve this?

The code snippet which I am trying to write to achieve is this:

```
            PathSequence:
            for(int i = 0; i < PathGraphRow; i++){
                if(PathGraph[i][0] == source){
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        nextNode = PathGraph[i][1];
                        resultantPaths[counter] = PathGraph[i][2];
                        prev = lightPathGraph[i][2];
                        if(nextNode == dest){
                            break PathSequence;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }else if(i > 0 && prev != PathGraph[i][2])
                    {
                        nextNode = PathGraph[i][1];
                        resultantPaths[counter] = PathGraph[i][2];
                        prev = PathGraph[i][2];
                        if(nextNode == dest){
                            break PathSequence;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

                if(nextNode == PathGraph[i][0] && prev != PathGraph[i][2]){
                    nextNode = PathGraph[i][1];
                    resultantPaths[counter] = PathGraph[i][2];
                    prev = PathGraph[i][2];
                    if(nextNode == dest){
                        break PathSequence;
                    }
                    counter++;                    
                }

                if(i == PathGraphRow-1 && PathGraph[i][2] != resultantPaths[counter]){
                    if(PathGraph[i][1] != dest){
                        resultantPaths = new int[PathCount];
                    }
                }

            }        
    }
```

Thank you.

Regards

Comment: You're certainly going to need a nested for loop, the outer one iterates over columns, the inner iterates over the current row. Beyond that I have no idea what you're asking. How can an array of integers store something like `2->4 = 502`? That makes no sense. It sounds like you're trying to go from one inappropriate storage method to an even worse one.

Comment: Have you ever thought of doing a 3d array?

Comment: I guess you are not actually looking for a 1D array but a graph. I suggest you go and learn about the data structure called graph.

Comment: @melpomene that would actually make sense, but the questions says a 1D array of integers. And it should actually be tuples since order matters and they should be 4 tuples since you could potentially have three values which lead to one (or more if the actual data set differs from the posted one). The third value in the tuple should be `null` or `-1` or something if it only requires two values like in the case of `2->4 = 500`.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I don't understand the 4-tuple bit but the 1D array is the output (the list of path IDs). What I described is the input (the graph structure).

Comment: OP could you have something like `2->4->6->8->10->12 = 500`? Or is there some limit on how many values can point to a `Path`? If you can post that much I can give a solution, although it will not be a 1D array of integers.

Comment: @melpomene If the path ID is of unknown length how do you know where one ends and the next begins? I said 4 tuple beacuse I thought you wanted all of the data, something like `<2, 4, 6, 500>` in the case of `500`.

Comment: @JustinGingyMcDonald: I have updated my code snippet.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: I am sorry that was only an illustration. I have posted the snippet now.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I'm assuming paths can be arbitrarily long and may overlap. You know a point is a path entry if it has no predecessor.

Comment: My illustration using "->" was confusing I suppose I am sorry. I only want to extract a sequence of integer from the third column which correspond to paths. So the path from "2" to "8" would be `500 501`

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: Yes paths are arbitrarily long and may overlap. As a part of the task, when two paths overlap I also need to eliminate the one of them which is less desirable (and may for instance not lead to the destination or be a longer path than the other)

Comment: Can you count on all paths going 2,4,6.....,30,32? If you only need the minimal and maximum values in the path to find the path the problem is much simpler.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal A path is identified by its entry/exit points and its weight (internal length).

Comment: @melpomene That didn't really answer my question. I was wondering if in this application, do all points in a path follow the increase by two pattern in the example or are they arbitrary as well?

Comment: Once I figure that out I'll start working on a solution. I will say now, your code is too simple. How can you expect to find all the paths looping over the columns only once? That's impossible. I'm sure there's probably a more efficient way but the straight forward implementation is going to go over the list `(length(length + 1))/2` times or `length^2` times, not sure which yet...

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: Thank you. You are correct. Right now the code works only in some cases. I shall try both `(length(length +1))/2` and `length^2` and see if I get better results.

Comment: Hi all, I have simplified my problem, hoping the solution would become simpler too. Now a sub-path being considered separately is not possible because all individual sub-paths which were represented by multiple rows in the 2D graph are simplified now and are represented by just one row, with its end points (I have updated the 2D array and also the question). So a single route which was "2" to "4" to "6" (ie: 500) would not be represented in the 2D array as a single row "2" to "6". Does this make any difference? What are the possibilities to finding a solution. Your hints awaited. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm overlooking some details the problem is fairly trivial without the sub paths. You just need a single for loop that is very specific.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
 {
      Path path = new Path(array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]);
      pathsArray.Add(path);
 }
```

That is of course pseudo code, but that's basically how I would do it. I would make each path a three tuple. I still don't quite get how you intend to store the data, if you put all the values in a 1D int array, how do you know where a path starts and ends? Assuming all paths are defined by a start, end, and result that would work in a 1D array although it would be worse to use than the 2D array. If paths are of arbitrary length there's no way to store the data in a 1D array. Anyways, here's code to put the table provided in a 1D array (assuming no greater complexity);

```
int[] paths = new int[2dArray.length * 3];
int mapper = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 2dArray.length; i++)
{
     paths[mapper] = 2dArray[i][0];
     paths[mapper + 1] = 2dArray[i][1];
     paths[mapper + 2] = 2dArray[i][2];
     mapper += 3;
}
```

Then to access the array you need to do a bunch of mod 3 crap to know which value you're getting...

```
 if (index % 3 == 0)
    //path start
 else if (index % 3 == 1)
    //path end
 else if (index % 3 == 2)
    // result of path
```